# Как передать с помощью HTML-формы массив данных в контроллер ASP.NET Core MVC POST-запросом?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Допустим есть у меня форма и в ней 3 поля для ввода числовых значений. И есть контроллер принимающий массив чисел POST-запросом. Как можно указать форме что нужно отправить массив, а не просто что-то одно.

Answer (score 0):

в .cshtml:

```
<form action="/Home/Test" method="post">
    <input id="test" name="test" type="text" value="" />
    <input id="test" name="test" type="text" value="" />
    <input id="test" name="test" type="text" value="" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

внутри контроллера:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Test(List<string> test)
{
    return null;
}
```

в test - список всех элементов с формы